# How to sleep until next Sunday

Tags: c++, boost

How can I sleep until next Sunday using boost? Can i convert `boost::gregorian::date` object to something that `boost::this_thread::sleep_until` can handle? Is it possible?

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::gregorian::date current_date(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
    boost::gregorian::greg_weekday next_sunday_date(boost::gregorian::Sunday);
    boost::gregorian::date next_weekday_date = next_weekday(current_date, next_sunday_date);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure want to "sleep until Sunday", and not "run something on Sunday"?

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I came up with.

*Note that I made the code generally more readable. This is important, not just for future maintenance, but also because it will allow you to "see the forest for the trees" - in turn allowing you to remember the important concepts mentally.*

At least, that helps me.

**Edit** DyP contributed a way to use `sleep_until` (which would behave more accurately in rare circumstances, e.g. where the clock would change during the sleep).

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::gregorian;
    using boost::posix_time::ptime;
    using clock = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock; // or: boost::posix_time::second_clock;

    auto today       = date(day_clock::local_day());
    auto at_sunday   = greg_weekday(Sunday);
    auto next_sunday = next_weekday(today, at_sunday);

#if 1
    auto as_tm         = to_tm(next_sunday);
    auto as_time_t     = mktime(&as_tm);
    auto as_time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(as_time_t);

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(as_time_point);
#else
    auto duration = (ptime(next_sunday) - clock::local_time());
    auto msecs    = duration.total_milliseconds();
    std::cout << msecs << "\n";

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(msecs));
#endif
}
```

See it **[compiling on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0dcfa1f938b5bbf)** (*obviously times out*)

Comment: Why don't you use `std::this_thread::sleep_until`? (a timepoint from `now` plus the duration if there's no conversion from boost's timepoint to C++11's timepoint; `sleep_until` takes into account clock adjustments)

Comment: @DyP Because I'm pragmatic. I spent 10 minutes finding out this interface. I had no incentive to find the way to go from Boost's `posix_time::timep` to `std::chrono` timepoints. It irked me, so if you know how to do the conversion, feel free to edit :)

Comment: I guess the simplest way to insert this would be `std::this_thread::sleep_until(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(msecs));`. I'll have a look if boost provides some conversion.

Comment: Maybe with a little help from C? [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0b64b14290a71fb) (those interfaces.... I had no idea..)

Comment: @DyP Yeah. That's quite an annoing series of hoops to have to jump. I'd always consider wrapping this into a more usable API before using. Thanks for the leg-work (you mind if I add it to the answer as an alternative?)

Comment: Go ahead. Not sure if it's any good, though. I've read a bit in the C Standard and it seems ok, but it feels wrong.

Comment: @DyP Thanks. I get that too, chrono is obiously not geared to calendaring, but to pure time/clock calculations. And whenever I "drop down" to C-level I feel I might be abusing the library abstractions. This time, I'm pretty sure it's ok, though.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds unstable. What if the user turns the computer off or goes into hibernation, or just does a restart?

I would do this in one of two ways:

1. Add a scheduled task(or whatever the windows/osx terminology is) / cronjob (linux) and set it to run on Sunday.
2. Add it to autostart and periodically(once per 10/30/60 minutes) check if it's Sunday.

Both ways handle restart/shut off/hibernation better than sleeping for 5 days.

Comment: It's ok in my case. I am only need to sleep until next sunday. That's all

Comment: Weird but fair enough. Have you tried just calculating the number of ticks/seconds until next sunday and sleeping that long?